# Is there a way in Joomla to have public user profiles?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7

I installed Joomla 1.7 and I noticed that you can have user profiles with the user profile plugin. However, is there a way to publicly access a user's profile (without loging in)?

For instance, I noticed that you can go to:

```
/index.php?option=com_users&view=profile
```

However, that seems to pull up my own profile, If I am logged out it always redirects you to the login form. I have tried adding additional variables like "id=1", "user_id=1", or "userId=1".

Is there a way to do this? Or will I have to develop a component to pull in this information publicly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though it not possible with clean Joomla website a lot of useful code come with it, which you could include to your component if you prefer to create one.

But... there is a great extension [Community Builder](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/community-builder) with a great team behind it. Having used it in the past, I would highly recommend it as a solution for community based sites.

It changes the login form to a much better & bug-free form, enables more fields to be created for registration, and allows special pages for individual users, plus, community builder has extension-specific plugins.

**EDIT**: This answer needs an update as since it was added more extensions have been introduced like JomSocial or **EasySocial**. I cannot recomment CommunityBuilder any more

Comment: so there is no way to do this without using a 3rd party component or building my own?

Comment: Don't think so, test CB you won't regret

Comment: CB is horribly inefficient.  Each time you create a new user field, that field is appended to the CB user table.  Every time a user is accessed - the entire table row is returned (not just what's needed, everything).  Their code is riddled with inline javascripts, hard-coded strings, 3rd party javascripts (instead of using the built-in utilities).  It's generally a pain to work with if you're doing anything more complex than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This post is tagged with Joomla 1.7 however I wanted to mention that if using Joomla 3.7.4 you now have the ability to show the User Profile plugin data from the core Contacts component. You can also add more custom fields to the Users component and they will also show from the Contacts component. You can set the display of the Users Profile info by going to the Admin panel -> Contacts -> Options. Turn on the option under; Contact -> User Profile -> set to "Show".